# How to replace values of latitude and longitude into one element value?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

[xml file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT5oF.png)
How to achieve this? 
you need to replace the values of the latitude and longitude in to one element value .

For example:
Existing one

```
<Longitude>-0.30365</Longitude>
<Latitude>51.61965</Latitude>
```

New one :
`<cordinate-point>-0.30365,51.619165<cordinate-point>`

Comment: Do you have those two elements inside a parent element container or do you have them in a sequence of elements?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes. The parent element is <root>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`xdmp:node-insert-before()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-insert-before) and [`xdmp:node-delete()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-delete) functions:

```
let $doc :- fn:doc("/uri/of/your/doc.xml")
let $long := $doc/root/Longitude
let $lat := $doc/root/Latitude
(: construct an element with text() value of the Longitude and Latitude elements :)
let $point := <cordinate-point>{string-join(($lat,$long), ",")}</cordinate-point>
return
  (
    (: insert a new coordinate-point element before the Longitude element :)
    xdmp:node-insert-before($long, $point),
    (: Remove the Longitude element :)
    xdmp:node-delete($long),
    (: Remove the Latitude element :)
    xdmp:node-delete($lat)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the document with XSLT using either [`xdmp:xslt-eval()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:xslt-eval) with a locally evaluated stylesheet or [`xdmp:xslt-invoke()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:xslt-invoke) with an installed XSLT, and then replace the existing document with the result of the transform using [`xdmp:node-replace()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace):

```
declare variable $XSLT := 
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--replace the Latitude element with a cordinate-point element -->
    <xsl:template match="Latitude">
        <cordinate-point>
            <xsl:value-of select="., ../Longitude" separator=","/>
        </cordinate-point>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--drop the Longitude element -->
    <xsl:template match="Longitude"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>;

let $doc := fn:doc("/uri/to/your/doc.xml")
return
    xdmp:node-replace($doc, xdmp:xslt-eval($XSLT, $doc))
```